# Is it possible to avoid header horizontal misalignment?

Tags: html, css, typography

Some letters occupy free space on the left. You can see it by highlighting the first letter "H" after running the snippet.

There is the same margin and padding in both header and paragraph elements, however the header is visibly shifted to the right, due to larger amount of empty space which its letter "H" occupies on the left due to its size, compared to letter "H" of the paragraph.

Is there any way to avoid such shift, except by playing with paddings for each case manually?

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Open Sans;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Hilariously small paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal behaviour, but if it really disturbs you that much, you can use a negative `text-indent` on the `h1` element, which will move the whole text a bit to the left:

```css
h1 {
  text-indent: -0.05em;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Open Sans;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Hilariously small paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: so, unfortunately it means i either have to shift the text for each case to find the ideal fit, or change the fonts to those which do not have much space around actual glyphs, right?

Answer (score 0):

There's not really much you can do about that. It will depend on the font you're using.

You'd just have to manually add a 2px padding or move the elements in some other way I suppose.

```
p {
    padding-left: 2px;
}
```

Comment: do you have an example of a font which does not have much free space around glyphs?

Comment: i suspect that only monospace fonts fit into such category

Comment: Yeah a font with no spacing probably isn't too common. Pretty much just have to manually correct these cases if you want to.